# Interactive image map in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I want to implement an interactive image map in android. I have to show an image map, have to show the location where user click and have to connect two locations in the image map. How can I implement this in Android.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to Create map XMl file to define Coordiantes of the image where you wnat to find click.

This link will help you to understand more...
https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap